# Schedule "string too long for attribute" query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, scheduler, create-table

I have several long (lines of SQL) Oracle queries that currently repeat daily as an SSIS package. The queries are all `Create Table AS Select...` with a bunch of joins, where clauses and selects.

The SSIS runs fine, but slow, due to nature of the linked server. Runs fine in SQL Developer. I am trying to move all queries into Oracle as scheduled jobs, but I am running into the "String value too long for attribute "job action" ORA16612. How to proceed? Tried to make a procedure of it using "Create Procedure...Begin.... execute immediate" but I get the same error on length.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: The code is 25 different queries and they are all about 200 lines.  Each one is similar. "Select, from, inner/left join, where/IN"  Each one has some 'to_char' and 'case'.  There are no variables.

Comment: Were you trying to create the job from dynamic SQL in a procedure; or trying to execute the original statement in a procedure that would then become the job action? (Odd to get the *same* error in the latter case; but if it's just similar, what is the actual error and how long is the statement?) Why are you regularly creating tables in the first place though? That isn't something you'd normally want to be doing in Oracle. Perhaps you want a permanent materialized view that is refreshed daily instead, or partitioning, or something...

Comment: First I tried to just put the original query into the scheduler.  For the smaller queries this worked okay, but for all the long ones I got eh error for long string value. I then did some internet searching and tried putting the original statement in a procedure.  I still got the same error. To put the original statement in a procedure I wrote: Create Procedure xxx IS BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'my script CTAS here'; End xxx;  I tried it also with (' my CTAS script here')

Comment: So the statement is more than 32k? But only 200 lines? You can build up a CLOB and use that as the dynamic statement.... but really, take a step back and see if this really something you need to be doing, or if there's a better way to achieve whatever your end goal for this daily table is.

Comment: Up to now I have been limited in what I can do on the Oracle database. I have been using SSIS for over a year because I didn't have scheduler privileges. I still don't have materialized view privileges, but that is probably better route. I could set it to update daily automatically. SSIS could then quickly query those tables.  Seems like a better plan IF I can get privileges. The other queries are 200-300 lines and each line is about 75 characters. I assume the limit I am hitting is the 4K character limit.

Comment: PL/SQL has a 32k limit for string literals, which is why I'm a bit confused. If you can't get MV privs and you're dropping and recreating the table daily, you could truncate and repopulate it instead. That could go in a procedure as static SQL (apart from the truncate, which would still have to be dynamic).

Comment: Got MVs privileges and created them. Then tried refresh and would only do complete which takes same time as creating table. There are no MV logs on the base tables and they won't change that. Back to same problem of trying to schedule a query to insert new rows daily by running query similar to build table query but with SysDate-1. Are spaced included in the 32k count for the string literals?

Comment: I go this figured out a while back and am now going back to clean up the question and answer.  I was trying to put the SQL into the scheduler.  Instead I created a procedure with all the queries.  Then I scheduled the procedure.  Has been working great.